# Eigenvalues of $8\times8$ non-diagonal matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2 - 6A + 9I_8 = 0_8$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

In an exam today I had the following problem:

> Let $A \in M_{8}(\mathbb{R})$ ($8\times8$ matrix with real entries) satisfying $$A^2 - 6A + 9I_8 = 0_8$$ Find the eigenvalues of $A$.

---

**My approach**

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, dotting both sides of the equation with $v$ gives
$$\lambda^2 + 6\lambda + 9 = 0 \implies (\lambda - 3)^2 = 0 \implies \lambda = 3.$$

On the other hand the given relation reads $(A - 3I_8)^2 = 0_8$ so
$$\det(A - 3I_8)^2 = 0 \implies \det(A - 3I_8) = 0.$$

Thus $3$ is always an eigenvalue of A, so we get $\text{Spec} A = {3}.$

**My question**

Why is it relevant that $A$ is nondiagonal? The only implication I could find is that considering the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $A$, we have
$$p(x) \mid (x - 3)^2 \Rightarrow p(x) = x-3 \text{  or  } p(x) = (x-3)^2.$$

But since $A$ is nondiagonal we can't have $p(x) = x - 3$ so $p(x) = (x-3)^2$. But I don't see why this would influence the eigenvalues of $A$.

So is the fact that $A$ is diagonal relevant?

Comment: The  size of the largest Jordan block for eigenvalue 3 is two. There may be one, or two, or three, or four such blocks in an 8 by 8 matrix.

Comment: It is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is similar to one or more little blocks on the diagonal, each
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3&1 \\
0&3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Whatever is left over is diagonal $3$